# Nesting Variables within a Variable

Tags: variables, sass, scope

Is it somehow possible  to nest several variables within one variable?
The code below doesn't throw an error, but I have no clue how to call the inner "first" or "second"

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    text: (
      first: black,
      second: grey
    ),
    button: blue
  ),
);
```

`map_get` doesn't seem to work because it's too deep nested.

**EDIT: The provided solution by Arkellys is basically working. The Problem I got now is that i want to automate this with the simple call of a function. The function should call a mixin where the theming should style my components.**

The mixin looks like that:

```
@mixin theme($themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    .theme-#{$theme} & {
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
      }

      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }
  }
}
```

and the function that calls the mixin looks like that:

```
@function theme($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
```

In my scss I call it like that:

```
.past {
  @include theme($themes) {
    color: theme('text-second');
  }
}
```

So how do I detect if i use a simple 1st level nesting or already a 2nd level nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and to get a value in your map you can use a `@function` such as [this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/#article-header-id-0) by Hugo Giraudel.

As an example:

```
@function getDeepMapValue($map, $keys...) {
   @each $key in $keys { $map: map-get($map, $key); }
   @return $map;
}

$themes: (
  light: (
    text: (
      first: black,
      second: grey
    )
  )
);

.class {
  color: getDeepMapValue($themes, light, text, first);
}
```

Will return:

```
.class {
  color: black;
}
```

---

**Edit:** If I understand your `@mixin` correctly, doing something along these lines should work. First, edit your `@function theme` to use `getDeepMapValue`:

```
@function theme($keys...) {
  @return getDeepMapValue($theme-map, $keys...);
}
```

And then:

```
.past {
  @include theme($themes) {
    color: theme(text, second); // grey
    background: theme(button); // blue
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's basically working, but I got a more complex problem by digging deeper in this. Please view my edited question

Comment: @Dominik I edited my answer. I am just not sure about how you want to send the arguments to `theme()`?